# How can I rename the "Font Family" dropdown in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I'd like it to simply be labeled "Font" as this is more useful to my non technical users.  I can't seem to find a way to do this.  Using version 4.x

Comment: you may have to override default files.

Answer (score 1):

you can change it in the tinymce.min.js file. just search for the text "Font Family" and you will see where you can change it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by changing the default value in `tinymce.min.js` file. Just search for the code part beginning with:

```
{type:"listbox",text:"Font Family",tooltip:"Font Family",values:i,
```

...
Then put your desired label (for example "Font") inside the  `text:""`. After change it should be look like :

`{type:"listbox",text:"Font",tooltip:"Font Family",values:i,`.

Result:[image: Result]

If you want to do this programmatically, for example create a button that will change label on click you can add this code when initializing tinyMCE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    toolbar1: 'fontselect fontsizeselect mybutton',
    //...
    // extra coding can go here
    //...
    setup: function(editor) {
    editor.addButton('mybutton', {
        text: 'My button',
        icon: false,
        onclick: function() {
            var fontlabel = "Font";
            document.getElementsByTagName("button")[4].firstChild.innerText = fontlabel;
            // getElementsByTagName is an array, so the index changes belonging to 
            // position of your "FontFamily" dropdown. In my example it' 6th.
        }
    });
    }
});
</script>
```

Before:[image: before button click]
After:[image: after button click]